# Prevent myself from accidentally emailing group

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2013, email-filter, sent-items

Yesterday at work I accidentally emailed our entire division on an email I had only intended for a single person. I think I accidentally selected the wrong auto-complete, since the name and the list start with the same letters. I would like to try to prevent myself from doing this again.

The best option would be if there's a way to pop-up and confirm whenever I am sending to certain recipients. Based on [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/541172/need-to-create-a-rule-in-outlook-to-warn-when-sending-to-certain-domains-email-a) that doesn't seem possible without installing additional software. That's something I want to avoid, as that requires getting admins involved to approve and install the software for me.

So far the best solution I've found is to create an Outlook rule that delays delivery to certain recipients. Hopefully then I'll notice it in the *Outgoing* box and can delete it before it gets sent, though I'm not entirely sure whether delays happen at the client side or on the server. If the latter, that won't work.

Are there any other ways I can prevent myself from accidentally emailing specific addresses?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a vb macro (below) to stop yourself sending to that address without confirming it ... but really you need to look at your habit of sending emails so quickly - does it matter if you spend 5 seconds looking at the address before hitting 'send' ?

```
Private Sub Application_ItemSend(ByVal Item As Object, Cancel As Boolean)

On Error Resume Next
 ' use lower case for the address 
 ' LCase converts all addresses in the To field to lower case
If InStr(LCase(Item.To), "bad@address.com") Then
      Prompt$ = "You sending this to " & Item.To & ". Are you sure you want to send it?"
       If MsgBox(Prompt$, vbYesNo + vbQuestion + vbMsgBoxSetForeground, "Check Address") = vbNo Then
         Cancel = True
       End If
  End If

End Sub
```

This macro needs to be added to ThisOutlookSession to work.

Comment: Thanks, this looks like it should work. And yes, I can just take the time to look at the address. This particular email was supposed to be a 5 second total "Here's the link we talked about".

Comment: Ah I know those emails well, you quickly type it out, hit send without thinking and whoops!

Ah well, it happens :)